# Trouble getting text_field_with_auto_complete to work on an overlay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-plugins, overlay

I have a slight issue with getting Auto Complete to search when the text field is on a modal overlay.

To achieve the auto complete I am using the plugin by Pat Shaughnessy ([link](http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/6/15/auto-complete-for-complex-forms-using-nested-attributes-in-rails-2-3)) and the modal overlay is created using the helpers in the "Modal Overlay" plugin.

I am trying to use the auto complete on a form that is displayed in the overlay. However using firebug I can see that nothing is happening when I type in the field (it works on all forms not on an overlay).

Is there anything extra I need to do to make the auto-complete work on an overlay or do you guys know of any better plugins I can use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help

*Ruby 1.8.6 and Rails 2.3.8*

Comment: This is the link to the modal overlay just for your information (I couldn't post 2 links) http://www.ericmethot.com/code/ruby/ruby/modaloverlay.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I gave up half a day after posting this question and wrote my own auto-complete function that is compatible with all overlays.